# Android market API

Tags: android, google-play

Does anyone know if the Android market has an API which enables to automatically submitting new applications, without having to fill-up the market form manually.

Comment: try this http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/

Answer (score 3):

No, sorry, there is no programmatic way to submit Market listings. Presumably, this is an anti-spammer measure.

Comment: They could solve that with some kind of for-pay-account. Google, are you listening?